# Why were the Matriarchs Barren?

Tags: genesis

The four matriarchs, Sara, Rivca, Rachel and Lea, were barren to demonstrate that their children, the ancestors of the Jewish people-forming tribes, were not born naturally, but by the power of the miracle of Divine Providence.

Comment: Betho's, 3 people have voted to have this question closed as "off-topic" because it does not appear to be about the analysis of biblical text within the scope defined in the help center.  It might also be helpful if you were to provide a source to support your claim about the four matriarchs.

Comment: Who is Rivca?  Some Bible verses are needed here.

Comment: She means Rebecca

Answer (score 1):

The Bible does not say why Sarai remained childless till age 90, or why Rebekah had to wait till she conceived.  Nor does the Bible shed any light on the situation of Rachael and her sister Leah.  When the Bible is silent on a particular question, it simply means we don’t need to know.

However, what we can know with certainty from the Bible is that the genealogy leading up to the birth of Jesus, the Messiah, was all under the control of God.  God is sovereign and it was His good will and pleasure to orchestrate events as part of His divine plan to redeem sinful humanity.

God gave Abram a vision in which He promised him a son and that his descendants would be as numerous as the stars in the sky (Genesis 15).  God was faithful to His promise.

Divine Providence was certainly at work, but we should speculate no further.  Unlike the conception of Jesus, where no man was involved, the four matriarchs were impregnated by their husbands.  The lesson to be learned is that God’s timing is always perfect and nothing can thwart His divine purpose.

Comment: Galatians 4:20-29;  ... ... ...

Comment: Oh, how I wish you had given the Bible verses when you asked your question, Betho's. Yes, Isaac was a child of promise. However, Scripture does not say Isaac was conceived by the Holy Spirit as Jesus was. Jesus' conception was unique.